# Getting battery information for Laptop and put it in label in C++

Tags: c++

I am doing an App for laptops Called Batterlizer,
It will get all the information about the battery, So everything was going well until I wanted to get the battery percent and other things , so here is my code:

```
SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS BatteryPower;

if(GetSystemPowerStatus( &BatteryPower ))

{

long unsigned int BatteryFull = BatteryPower.BatteryLifeTime;

const char BatteryFullTime[900] = {BatteryFull};

BatteryLeftText =  CreateWindow("static", "Battery Life:",WS_CHILD | 

WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 0, 0, 100, 20,hwnd, (HMENU)(501),(HINSTANCE) 

GetWindowLong (hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);

UpdatedBatteryText = CreateWindow("static",BatteryFullTime, WS_VISIBLE | 

WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 90, 0, 50, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)(501),(HINSTANCE) 

GetWindowLong (hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),NULL);

}
```

the problem is , it says strange letters when it comes to BatteryFullTime,
Any Ideas guys?

Comment: p.s: I have been working for Java,PAWN,LUA,C#,HTML,PHP and some more before but I am kinda new in C++ that is why :)

Comment: I can't display the
BatteryPower.BatteryLifeTime inside
UpdatedBatteryText = CreateWindow("static",BatteryFullTime, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 90, 0, 50, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)(501),(HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong (hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),NULL);
I tried everything but still not working.

Comment: Use `SetWindowText()` to set the text of the control. Also what is going on with `const char BatteryFullTime[900] = {BatteryFull};
`?

Comment: I already tried what you said above but it doesn't work :/ it returns "y" letter with 2 dots on it, and I did const char BatteryFullTime[900] = {BatteryFull}; 
cause I thought it might work if I did that but still I couldn't fix my problem :/

Comment: Try the following: `char szBatteryLifeBuffer[900]; sprintf(szBatteryLifeBuffer, "%lu", BatteryFull); SetWindowText(UpdatedBatteryText, szBatteryLifeBuffer);`

Comment: omg ! it works! ty a lot man! you made my day! please post it in a comment so I can choose it as the best answer <3

Comment: Always happy to help a fellow programmer :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
   char szBatteryLifeBuffer[900] = {0}; 
   sprintf(szBatteryLifeBuffer, "%lu", BatteryFull); 
   SetWindowText(UpdatedBatteryText, szBatteryLifeBuffer);

   // This also should work, too. 
   // SendMessage(UpdatedBatteryText, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTSTR)szBatteryLifeBuffer);
```

Get rid of

```
// This does not work.
const char BatteryFullTime[900] = {BatteryFull};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using C instead of C++, that makes it harder. In C++ :

```
std::string BatteryFullTime = std::to_string(BatteryFull);
```

No need to care about length, or remember details of the conversion function. However:

```
SetWindowText(UpdatedBatteryText, BatteryFullTime.c_str());
```

The Windows function does need a C string, but it's easy to get a C string from the C++ string.

Comment: I am using C++ dude not C

Comment: @Eth. : That's not visible from the code snippet you posted.

Comment: Well but it is C++ I am sure :) as it is main.cpp